# Complex Attributes in Android Custom View XML

Tags: android, xml, view, android-custom-view

I've got a question on custom view XML-declarations.
I created my own View with the custom attributes as normal. Now I want to add more complex attributes like this: (This is non-working code)

```
<com.xxx.yyy.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/customTextView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonBlack"
    android:text="TextView" >
        <Animation
            animation:property1="123"
            animation:property2="456" />
        <Animation
            animation:property1="789"
            animation:property2="012" >
        </Animation>
</com.xxx.yyy.CustomTextView>
```

I didnt find a way to do this on my own but maybe someone has got an idea.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I just solved the problem more or less nicely.
I created a new .xml file in my /res/xml folder called animations.xml

```
<animations>
    <animation
        name="Animation name 1"
        float1="1.1"
        float2="1.2"
        integer1="11"
        integer2="12" />
    <animation
        name="Animation name 2"
        float1="2.1"
        float2="2.2"
        integer1="21"
        integer2="22" />
</animations>
```

My custom view in attrs.xml contains an attribute which is used to reference the animations.xml file from above:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
    <attr name="animations" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Now i parse the referenced .xml file in the constructor of the MyTextView as described here: http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/12/14/using-xml-file-resources-in-android/

Maybe this helps somebody at some time.

Comment: You should create custom XML attributes for this like described here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `CustomTextView` extends `ViewGroup` (or has it in it's class hierarchy) and `Animation` is a custom view you've defined, this will not work. Only `Views` and `ViewGroups` are allowed in layout XML files (and some special tags defined by Android like `include` and `merge`), and only ViewGroup elements can have child elements.

Comment: Okay thanks! That is exactly what i thought. I was just hoping that there is a way of doing this which i havent seen yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom XML attributes to your custom view like this:

```
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="YourCustomClass">
    <attr name="someCustomAnimationAttribute" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>

<resources>
```

How you obtain it is described here:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr

In your layout you have to declare a namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and then use it like this:

```
<com.xxx.yyy.CustomTextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/customTextView1"
android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonBlack"
android:text="TextView" 
app:someCustomAnimationAttribute="@drawable/someAnimation">
```

That way you can supply those animations via XML instead of adding them as as child elements which is not possible.

Comment: i think the OP's main concern is how to retrieve a child xml tag in a custom view, i.e. `<Animation />`

Comment: As @Karakuri pointed out, if that custom view extends `ViewGroup`, one can add child views (custom child views with custom parameters for that matter). But supplying an animation that way won't work.

Comment: Yes exactly. I already knew how to define simple attributes. The question was whether it is possible to define more complex attributes as XML child elements. But thanks anyway!